# How to store the output of a function into separate data frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to process several data frames using a function, and store the result in the separate respective data frames. However, the function does not seem to store the variable correctly.

Here is the function:

```
def customize_df(in_df,out_df,old_col_val,new_col_val,vol):
    out_df = in_df.copy()
    # Adjust hemisphere contigent values
    if 'lh' in out_df:
        out_df.columns = out_df.columns.str.replace('lh_', 'L_')
    if 'rh' in out_df:
        out_df.columns = out_df.columns.str.replace('rh_', 'R_')
    # Adjust column names.
    out_df.columns = out_df.columns.str.replace(old_col_val, new_col_val)
    # Change the name of the first column to ID.
    out_df.columns = out_df.columns.str.replace(out_df.columns[0], "ID")
    # Make Volumetric eTIV adjustments
    if vol==True:
        df_raw = out_df.copy()
        df_raw.columns = df_raw.columns.str.replace('_Vol', '_Vol_Raw')
        df_raw.columns = df_raw.columns.str.replace('_volume', '_Vol_Raw')
        df_raw = pd.DataFrame(data = df_raw, columns= df_raw.columns)
        df2 = out_df.copy()
        df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('_volume', '_Vol_Adj')
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = df2, columns= df2.columns)
        cols = out_df.columns[out_df.columns.str.contains('_Adj')].tolist()
        for col in cols:
            df2[col] = df2[col].div(df2['eTIV'], axis=0)
        df_combined= df_raw.join(df2, rsuffix='_DROP')
        cols = df_combined.columns[df_combined.columns.str.contains('_DROP')].tolist()
        for col in cols:
            df_combined = df_combined.drop([col], axis=1)
        out_df = df_combined.copy()
        return out_df
    elif vol==False:
        return out_df
```

It works as intended, however, when I run then function with multiple sequential inputs, the results do not seem to be stores into "out_df", as intended.

Here are the commands:

```
customize_df(lh_exvivo_Area,'lh_ExV_Area','_exvivo_area','_ExV_Area',vol=True)

customize_df(Sub_GM_Vol,'Sub_GM_Vol','','_Sub_GM_Vol',vol=True)

customize_df(Sub_WM_Vol,'Sub_WM_Vol','','_Sub_WM_Vol',vol=True)
```

When I test it out by typing in the name of the desired output data frame, there is no result.

```
lh_ExV_Area.head()

NameError: name 'lh_ExV_Area' is not defined
```

Comment: you can't dynamically create the variable as you are trying to do here. modifying the `globals()` dict is not recommended

Comment: Maybe assign each to a new variable each time you run your function, instead

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks for the info! Do you think this would be a good solution? lh_ExV_Area= customize_df(lh_exvivo_Area,'lh_ExV_Area','_exvivo_area','_ExV_Area',vol=True)

Comment: you can store your dataframes in a `dict` where the `key` is the name you want to give it, I don't know what would be best for your use-case since I lack context but what I suggested is just one option.

Comment: You may wish to try deepcopy from the copy module copy. 'Deep copy is a process in which the copying process occurs recursively. It means first constructing a new collection object and then recursively populating it with copies of the child objects found in the original. In case of deep copy, a copy of object is copied in other object. It means that any changes made to a copy of object do not reflect in the original object. In python, this is implemented using “deepcopy()” function.'  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/

Comment: @arkadiy, that's what I would do, assign to a variable, then you can make a list or dict of the variables after each is created. The other option would be to make a dict, as aws_apprentice pointed out, but generally it's more readable to name each on its own